# Python Twisted: How to stop TLS?

Tags: python, encryption, twisted, ssl

There are a few examples here of how to start TLS after a connection is already otherwise established. I can't find however a way to do the opposite, turn off TLS.
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html

Could I just generate a one time random password for the client, exchange it using TLS, reconnect again, and just ask the client for that password to avoid connection hijacking?
Is there a way to do this without losing the connection?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? _Once set up_, TLS-protected connections are almost as cheap as unencrypted ones.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: After the authentication is complete, the client will start exchanging files with the server, these files will have to be client-side encrypted, as not even the server should be able to read them, so there will be a redundant client-side encryption step, and needless CPU time waste on the server-side decryption as well.

Comment: You should probably benchmark the cpu time used with TLS intact vs. the cpu time with no TLS at all, to make sure it really matters. I suspect it won't make enough difference that it's worth spending time figuring out how to reconnect with sufficiently secure auth tokens or how to turn off TLS on an existing connection.

Comment: @thepaul Benchmarking is an _excellent_ idea. Measure, don't speculate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid connection hijacking if you stop TLS.  Once you've terminated the protections on that connection, all bets are off: the benefits of TLS only last as long as the encrypted session persists.

I don't think that stopping TLS is supported, but really, there's no good reason to do it unless you need to do some seriously weird low-level stuff with your connection like handing it off to some other piece of hardware at the level of routing.  Even then, there are probably better ways to do it.